# How to resolve "The type com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE is not accessible" with Java11?

Tags: java, migration, java-11

I am trying to migrate my application from Java 8 to Java 11. In of one of my project classes, I have the line `Security.addProvider(new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());`. I am getting a compile error for this line. How to resolve this?

Comment: Try to just remove the line. You should not rely on a specific provider.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, welcome to StackOverflow!  When asking a question, please make sure to provide as much information as possible. In this case it was a bit unclear what error you get and when (I assume it's a compile error, so I added that.)

Comment: Yeah, it's a compile error, thanks Nicolai.

Comment: @Daniel, see my answer  and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can't access com.sun packages without explicitly setting them on your compile options. After adding `--add-exports=java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider=ALL-UNNAMED` to compilerArgs it compiles without any error.

Code:

```
   Security.addProvider(new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());
```

Maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-exports=java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`java.security.Security.getProviders()` returns you all the providers including the SunJCE.

```
   Stream.of(java.security.Security.getProviders()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

So better option to get the SunJCE instane is `java.security.Security.getProvider("SunJCE")`

Comment: Could you please tell me what should be the fix if I face the same issue at runtime ?
I tried  CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.5.jar" --add-exports java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider=ALL-UNNAMED but its not working