# Getting cannot access class com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE (in module java.base) error during Tomcat startup

Tags: java, maven

Currently we are trying to compile code in JDK 8 and run it in OpenJDK 17.
But during Tomcat startup I am getting below error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.test.TestXYZ cannot access class com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export com.sun.crypto.provider to unnamed module 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:489)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347
```

This issue is occurring when we are trying to add instance of `com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE` to `java.security.Security` by calling addProvider() method of `java.security.Security` class

I tried the the fix mentioned in [How to resolve "The type com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE is not accessible" with Java11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957114/how-to-resolve-the-type-com-sun-crypto-provider-sunjce-is-not-accessible-with) but it didnt work may be because
this is to fix compile time issue. Not sure though.

Could you please help me resolving this issue ?

**POM Entry :**

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-exports=java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**Tomcat Version :**  9.0.36

Thank you

Comment: Why on Earth do you want to do this? Every Sun, Oracle and now OpenJDK build of Java since at least 2000 (_long_ before j8) includes SunJCE in the provider list automatically, and on the few systems that don't include it (like IBM-AIX Java and I _think_ Android) it isn't available at all so your program would make itself unusable.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Any idea why I am getting that error if its already provided ?

Comment: First if you are on JDK17 I strongly recommend to use most recent versions of maven plugins and not a nine year old version ....furthermore it looks like the test is using java module system?

Comment: Your code, if not modified for the new module rules in 9 up, can't access a `com.sun` class by _name_. You can access _algorithms_ from the _provider_ by calls like `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding","SunJCE")` where the _class_ your code accesses is `javax.crypto.Cipher` and _that_ _internally_ accesses the `com.sun` classes which _it_ can do because _it_ has been modified to follow the new module rules. Or put more simply, module accessibility is not automatically transitive.